# ctrl+drag not working on Xamarin Studio on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin-studio

`Ctrl`+ `click and drag` is not working in the iOS designer in Xamarin Studio.

Is there any way to fix this? I have uploaded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kwg8vtE3T8&feature=youtu.be) showing what happens.

Comment: Xamarin studio's iOS Designer is buggy. Use Xcode's designer. In solution explorer, Right click on your Storyboard file > Open With > Xcode Interface Builder. Also it is very slow to load.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Interface builder (built in to Xcode) as it it must more stable and able to do much more (esp. in autolayout constraints).

To make the switch easier I would also recommend [Colby Williams's](https://twitter.com/colbylwilliams) add-in for Xamarin studio to make interface builder the default designer see this [blog post](http://www.colbylwilliams.com/2016/09/26/default-designer.html)

Also here is the [source](https://github.com/colbylwilliams/DefaultDesigner)